# SQL count string matches in each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Please take a look at this simple SQL server database :
[image: database]

What I want is, I want to create a summary with only 3 column, here is the code:

```
select ProductID, Name,
       *code* as CountString
from product
where Name in ('this', 'is', 'count', 'example')
```

I want the result to have 3 column, and the column "CountString" is the total number of string that matches ('this','is', 'count', 'example'). Here is the result I want :

[image: Result]

So for example, I want the Countstring for ProductID 1 is 4, because it contains all of 4 words.

If you can solve this, it would be amazing!

Comment: Tag the question with the database you are using.  Also edit the question and show the results that you want.

Comment: done! here you go

Comment: @RaspiSurya If a word appears multiple times, should it be counted multiple times or does that count as 1?

Comment: If there is a product name "this is called this sentence", it should be count as 5 words. Can you solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select ProductID, Name,
       ( (case when Name like '%this%' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when Name like '%is%' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when Name like '%count%' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when Name like '%example%' then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as CountString
from product;
```

Note:  Any `Name` that has "this" also has "is".

If "words" are separated by spaces (and only spaces), you can do:

```
select ProductID, Name,
       ( (case when concat(' ', Name, ' ') like '% this %' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when concat(' ', Name, ' ') like '% is %' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when concat(' ', Name, ' ') like '% count %' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when concat(' ', Name, ' ') like '% example %' then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as CountString
from product;
```

Comment: If there is a product name "this is called this sentence", it should be count as 5 words. Can you solve?

Comment: @RaspiSurya . . . Can you ask another question?  The answer would look rather different.

Comment: please sir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857407/sql-count-string-matches

Answer (score 0):

The following query should suffice your need ---

```
SELECT PRODUCTID,
       NAME,
       REGEXP_COUNT(NAME, 'this|is|count|example', 1, 'c') CountString
  FROM product;
```

This query will result in "Case Sensitive" checking, means only "example" will be counted not "Example". If you want "Case Insensitive" checking just put 'i' instead of 'c'.

Comment: what is REGEXP_COUNT? 

here is the error :
`Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'REGEXP_COUNT' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: REGEXP_COUNT is an Oracle build in function. I think you need it for SQL Server. Looking for the substitute.. Will post it once found.

Comment: It seems like there is no substitute of REGEXP_COUNT in SQL SERVER. So stick to what Gordon Linoff has shared.