# SQL count string matches

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please take a look at this simple SQL server database :

[image: database]

I want the result to have 3 column, and the column "CountString" is the total number of string that matches ('this','is', 'count', 'example'). 
I have managed to detect those words using this query, but it can`t detect multiple words :

```
SELECT
  productid,
  NAME,
  ((CASE
    WHEN Concat(' ', NAME, ' ') LIKE '% this %' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) + (CASE
    WHEN Concat(' ', NAME, ' ') LIKE '% is %' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) + (CASE
    WHEN Concat(' ', NAME, ' ') LIKE '% count %' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) + (CASE
    WHEN
      Concat(' ', NAME, ' ') LIKE '% example %' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END)) AS CountString
FROM product;
```

However, if the name for productID 1 is "this is count this example". I want it to be counted as 5. Could you solve this ?

Comment: mysql or  (MS)SQL-Server?

Comment: @Raspi Surya - Is word from string always seprated by space?

Comment: yes always separated by space. and it is sql server

Comment: @RaspiSurya i made some changes to code it will work as you expected

Comment: op, how about you try solving problems alone first before posting, also mark answeres as correct sometimes, ppl. are working for you. (and pls learn to write better english, it is not that hard)

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table product(productid int, NAME varchar(100))
Insert Into product Values(1,'this is this example')
Insert Into product Values(2,'this is this this count this example')


 SELECT productid,count(*) as CountString
 FROM
 (
     SELECT A.[productid],  
         Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
     FROM  (SELECT [productid],  
             CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([NAME], ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
         FROM  product) AS A 
     CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
 ) As Word
 WHERE String in ('this','is','count','example')
 Group by productid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @TableString TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,String nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @TableString(String)
SELECT 'this is count this example' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bearing Ball' UNION ALL
SELECT 'BB Ball Bearing ' UNION ALL
SELECT 'this is   example'

-- Here the delimeter is space 
SELECT id AS productid, COUNT(stringValue) AS StringValueCount FROM
 (
 SELECT id ,
        Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS stringValue
    FROM (
        SELECT id,CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(String, ' ', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS String
        FROM @TableString
        ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
    )Dt

WHERE  dt.stringValue in ('this','is','count','example')
GROUP BY id
```

Result

```
productid      StringValueCount
-----------------------------
   1                5
   4                3
```

Comment: product ID 2 and 3 should be 0. Since they don't have ('this','is', 'count', 'example').

Comment: You want to count only for the string 'this is count this example' ?