# MySQL search engine query not returning all results

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has the tables 'releases' and 'releases_index'. Each row in the releases table has an ID, and the index table contains keywords related to every row of the releases table. There are multiple keywords for each row of the releases table.

I am trying to create a query that searches the index table for one or more keywords and counts how many matches there are for each keyword, returning the results in order of matches starting with the best match.

This is what I have so far:

```sql
SELECT index_releaseId, COUNT(1) as count FROM releases_index
WHERE index_value LIKE '%apple%' AND index_value LIKE '%banana%'
GROUP BY index_releaseId
ORDER BY count DESC
```

The problem with this is that it would only return results where index_value has both 'apple' and 'banana' in the same row, whereas I need it to return results if the same release ID has separate keywords for 'apple' and 'banana'.

If index_releaseId 1 has two keywords (apple and banana) then I expect to get this result:

```
index_releaseId   count
1                 2
```

I hope I have explained this clearly. Essentially it's just a search engine.

Can anyone advise the best way to do this?

**UPDATE:**
Here is a hopefully clearer example of what I want

Say this is the releases_index table:

```
# index_id, index_releaseId, index_value
'435101', '21956', 'Scarlet Witch'
'435104', '21956', 'Television'
'435102', '21956', 'WandaVision'
'435109', '21998', 'WandaVision'
```

If in my search engine I search for 'scarlet witch wandavision', release ID 21956 would be a result. Although 21998 matched on one phrase, it wouldn't be a result as it doesn't have rows that match 'scarlet' or 'witch'. In terms of the query above, the result should look like this:

```
# index_releaseId, count
'21956', '2'
```

If i searched for just 'wandavision' both 21956 and 21998 would be results:

```
# index_releaseId, count
'21956', '1'
'21998', '1'
```

Hopefully this clarifies what I'm looking for, however, I am finding it difficult to explain.

Comment: can index_value  be the same apple and bananna at the same time in a row, please add a [mre]

Comment: I suppose so - not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: every row you select has to have index_value  apple **and** banana, else iz will not be chosen, so show us example data and wanted rsult so that we can help you

Comment: @Josh, is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839161/sql-count-string-matches-in-each-row) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Eugene I don't think so I'm afraid

Comment: @nbk I have added an example

Answer (score 0):

look at this. now i add 1 if i found apple and also 1 if i found banana.
The only thing is if there more then onetime apple in the string i also only add 1.

```
SELECT 
  index_releaseId,
  SUM((index_value LIKE '%apple%') + (index_value LIKE '%banana%')) as count 
FROM releases_index
WHERE index_value LIKE '%apple%' AND index_value LIKE '%banana%'
GROUP BY index_releaseId
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking for

Comment: @Josh - I have change my answer